# persisting pubnub uuid through browser refresh. Using Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pubnub

**Setup.**
I'm using the Javascript SDK for pubnub and the client is specifically a react app that is being served from S3.
I'm subscribing the client to the pubnub instance's UUID

```
  this.service = new PubNubService({
    pubnub:this.pubnub,
    channel:[this.pubnub.getUUID()]
});
```

The PubNubService object is the same as in the pubnub React App tutorial. That client is publishing to a general channel (testing-chat) which a BLOCK is listening to:

```
sendMessage() {
    this.pubnub.publish({
        channel:["testing-chat"],
        message: {
            text:this.refs.input.value,
            sender: this.pubnub.getUUID()

        }
    });
    this.setState({ currentMessage:"" })
```

The BLOCK then publishes a message back to the client's channel on after publish event handler (channel is named after their UUID).

**Desired Behavior.** I want to allow each client to have their own private conversation with the BLOCK and be able to access their own particular/private channel's history.

**Actual behavior.** The conversation breaks every time a user refreshes the browser because it sets a new UUID and therefore the history is wiped because it subscribes the client to a channel based on the new UUID.

**Question.** Is there a way I can persist the client's UUID through browser refresh with this current setup? Is there a different unique identified I can use/set that would persist through browser refresh, yet still be unique for every client? Or more importantly, how would you go about accomplishing the desired behavior ?

Comment: Don't call getUUID() because PubNub JS SDK is already persisting/reusing a UUID for you in localStorage. You set your own UUID and it should be stored in localStorage for you to be reused but you can do the localStorage set/get on your own, too.

Comment: That makes total sense. Will do, thanks for the heads up.